# MySQL: Replication is paused with both threads running, System Lock in ProcessList

Tags: mysql, replication

I have just set up Master Slave replication from a MariaDB EC2 instance to a MySQL RDS instance.

What can I do?

The Seconds_Behind_Master are increasing, never decreasing.

```
Slave_IO_State  Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host MY-HOST-IP^^^
Master_User slave
Master_Port 3306
Connect_Retry   60
Master_Log_File mysql-bin.000001
Read_Master_Log_Pos 100980741
Relay_Log_File  relaylog.000051
Relay_Log_Pos   642918
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysql-bin.000001
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
Replicate_Do_DB 
Replicate_Ignore_DB 
Replicate_Do_Table  
Replicate_Ignore_Table  mysql.plugin, innodb_memcache.cache_policies, mysql.rds_sysinfo, mysql.rds_replication_status, mysql.rds_history, innodb_memcache.config_options
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table 
Last_Errno  0
Last_Error  
Skip_Counter    0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos 59472980
Relay_Log_Space 43275177
Until_Condition None
Until_Log_File  
Until_Log_Pos   0
Master_SSL_Allowed  No
Master_SSL_CA_File  
Master_SSL_CA_Path  
Master_SSL_Cert 
Master_SSL_Cipher   
Master_SSL_Key  
Seconds_Behind_Master   11515
```

On issuing SHOW PROCESSLIST:

```
2
rdsadmin
localhost:45313
mysql
Sleep
7
NULL

1068173
root
86.108.98.236:58747
NULL
Sleep
671
NULL

1068174
system user
NULL
Connect
672
Waiting for master to send event
NULL

1068175
system user
NULL
Connect
11643
System lock
NULL

1068190
root
IP-COMES-HERE^^^:46621
NULL
Query
0
init
```

You can see a SYSTEM LOCK.

The master sees the slave, and it was working previously.

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS shows:

```
=====================================
2015-06-01 18:28:41 2b7f6b841700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 8 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 78727 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 10037 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 88762
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 38816
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 40463
Mutex spin waits 99825, rounds 246233, OS waits 4479
RW-shared spins 13615, rounds 397880, OS waits 13032
RW-excl spins 341, rounds 642345, OS waits 21206
Spin rounds per wait: 2.47 mutex, 29.22 RW-shared, 1883.71 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2015-06-01 10:43:38 2b7f6b986700  Cannot drop table `developer_dev`.`app`
because it is referenced by `market_dev_2`.`offer`
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 2593136
Purge done for trx's n:o < 2593135 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 3137
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 1068194, OS thread handle 0x2b7f6b841700, query id 4801324 IP HERE root init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 2591367, not started
MySQL thread id 1068174, OS thread handle 0x2b7f6b535700, query id 0 Waiting for master to send event
---TRANSACTION 2581507, not started
MySQL thread id 1068173, OS thread handle 0x2b7f6abd0700, query id 4788653 86.108.98.236 root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 2592991, not started
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x2b7f6a3d2700, query id 4801176 localhost 127.0.0.1 rdsadmin cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 2593135, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 0 sec flushing log
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 1068175, OS thread handle 0x2b7f6b2ab700, query id 4801320 System lock
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 1; buffer pool: 0
992 OS file reads, 2680197 OS file writes, 1725299 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 6.50 writes/s, 6.37 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 5449511, node heap has 1866 buffer(s)
18.37 hash searches/s, 7.75 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 2542366583
Log flushed up to   2542365001
Pages flushed up to 2534173043
Last checkpoint at  2534173043
1 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
662171 log i/o's done, 6.50 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 2818179072; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 208221
Buffer pool size   168064
Free buffers       77382
Database pages     88816
Old database pages 32621
Modified db pages  1686
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 104, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 889, created 87927, written 1554696
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 88816, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9962
Database pages     10813
Old database pages 3971
Modified db pages  180
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 150, created 10663, written 320364
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 10813, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9595
Database pages     11180
Old database pages 4106
Modified db pages  187
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 73, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 58, created 11122, written 60499
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11180, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9930
Database pages     10845
Old database pages 3983
Modified db pages  64
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 54, created 10791, written 33280
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 10845, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9641
Database pages     11132
Old database pages 4089
Modified db pages  328
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 126, created 11006, written 271895
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11132, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9429
Database pages     11345
Old database pages 4167
Modified db pages  224
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 3, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 133, created 11212, written 303361
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11345, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9540
Database pages     11235
Old database pages 4127
Modified db pages  194
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 12, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 127, created 11108, written 189494
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11235, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9455
Database pages     11319
Old database pages 4158
Modified db pages  244
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 16, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 130, created 11189, written 193531
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11319, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   21008
Free buffers       9830
Database pages     10947
Old database pages 4020
Modified db pages  265
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 111, created 10836, written 182272
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 10947, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 19950, id 47826225891072, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 11878528, updated 844596, deleted 8, read 732065066
3.37 inserts/s, 9.62 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 9.62 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

MySQL version is 5.6.22

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80970/mysql-slave-stuck-at-system-lock-most-of-the-time-high-cpu-usage

Comment: The duplicate assumes that LOAD DATA was issued, and there is no accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

AWS may be throttling the IOs of the RDS Instance. You should check the IO level of your RDS instance.