# Need to make MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE load large data faster

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to load 4 million rows of data into a MySQL InnoDB table using LOAD DATA INFILE and would like to know if there are server configuration options I can tweak to get faster load.

It took me 15 minutes to loaded 2 million rows, a performance I thought was disappointing for the LOAD DATA INFILE. My statement looks like this

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/file.csv'
>   INTO TABLE table FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ','
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
>   IGNORE 1 LINES (column1, column2, etc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although LOAD DATA INFILE can work against InnoDB, there are too many ways InnoDB gets tapped to its limits before swapping and bottlenecks takeover.

Here is a Pictorial Representation of InnoDB (from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

The bottlenecks would be goring through the following structures

- InnoDB Buffer Pool
- Transaction Logs (ib_lofile0, ib_logfile1)
- Double Write Buffer
- Insert Buffer
- One Rollback Segment
- Log Buffer

Here are some of my past posts where I discuss LOAD DATA INFILE with InnoDB

- `Feb 06, 2012` : [LOAD DATA (400k rows) INFILE takes about 7 minutes, cannot kill the "logging slow query" process?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12304/load-data-400k-rows-infile-takes-about-7-minutes-cannot-kill-the-logging-slo/12340#12340)
- `Jan 11, 2013` : [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE slows by 80% after a few gigs of input with InnoDB engine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31752/mysql-load-data-infile-slows-by-80-after-a-few-gigs-of-input-with-innodb-engine/31791#31791)
- `Jan 12, 2013` : [What does 'system lock' mean in mysql profiling a LOAD DATA INFILE statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31823/what-does-system-lock-mean-in-mysql-profiling-a-load-data-infile-statement/31824#31824)

## SUGGESTION #1

Break up the file into 20 smaller files.

Instead of one `LOAD DATA INFILE` against a 2 million row file, perform 20 `LOAD DATA INFILE` against 20 files, each with 100 thousand rows.

The Benefit : Less pressure against the InnoDB Plumbing

## SUGGESTION #2 (Optional)

- Increase the Log Buffer ([innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) = 256M)
- Increase the Write Threads ([innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) = 16)
- Increase the InnoDB Buffer Pool Size ([innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size))

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet that you are currently I/O bound.  This means that nothing can speed it up.  (And Rolando's suggestions may be futile.)

Let's look deeper.  Is this LOAD a recurring task?  If so, how often?  Is everything blocked waiting for table to be reloaded?  Simple solution:  Load into a different table, then do a double `RENAME TABLE` to swap it in.  Only milliseconds of downtime.

Is the data coming from another machine?  Use the network for the "input" side of the `LOAD` rather than having the one disk fighting for reads versus writes.

Do you have a lot of indexes?  There are several directions to take this question.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before barking up these tree(s).

Does the entire load need to be a single transaction?  Multiple transactions *may* be faster because of not overflowing the log file.  (I've seen 2x.)